# Regex in dreamweaver and notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, dreamweaver

I have a problem. I need to use regex in notepad++ or dreamweaver or someother editor to handle a large number of .html files. 
I need to find all html files that contains line below - but - there is a important thing.

```
/myfolder/401(something)a.js
```

It must find files that contains line above but ONLY those files that have at least one digit between

```
/myfolder/401(at least one digit 0-9)c.js!!!
```

It can contain letters but it must have in one place between 201------a.js at least one or more digits.
If there is no digits between 401--a.js than skip it(dont mark that one).
For example:

```
/myfolder/401dhfgsadfdf1a.js
/myfolder/401d7sd7fdf8a.js
```

Those above mark as correct but:

```
/myfolder/401dfdsfsdfsa.js
```

The above don't mark because it doesn't contain not a single digit between 401 and a.js
Is there any regex expert around here? Thank's in advance for any help.

Comment: `/myfolder/401.*\d.*a\.js` works in Notepad++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside notepad++ i ran this query in the find dialog

```
/myfolder/401.*\d.*a\.js
```

Locate something that starts with /myfolder/401 > has anything with at least a digit > a.js

With the following as my test data

```
/myfolder/401dhfgsadfdf1a.js
/myfolder/401d7sd7fdf8a.js
/myfolder/401dfdsfsdfsa.js
```

and the result of "File all in Current Document" were:

```
Search "/myfolder/401.*\d.*a\.js" (2 hits in 1 file)
  new  2 (2 hits)
    Line 1: /myfolder/401dhfgsadfdf1a.js
    Line 2: /myfolder/401d7sd7fdf8a.js
```

Comment: It does work! Thank you very much. That's what I was searching for!